# Gate is not connected to a submodule error

Tags: omnet++

I am trying to create a network with six nodes as following

```
module Node
{
    parameters:
        @display("i=abstract/router_vs");
    gates:
       inout g[];

}

channel Link extends ned.DatarateChannel
{
    parameters:
        int cost = default(0);
}

//
// Generated network with random topology (6 nodes, 8 edges, seed=100).
//
network net
{
    @display("bgb=478,329");
    submodules:
        S: Node {
            @display("p=19,87;is=s");
        }
        n1: Node {
            @display("p=130,142;is=s");
        }
        n2: Node {
            @display("p=130,36;is=s");
        }
        n3: Node {
            @display("p=262,142;is=s");
        }
        n4: Node {
            @display("p=262,36;is=s");
        }
        T: Node {
            @display("p=364,87;is=s");
        }
    connections:
        S.g++ <--> Link {  cost = 13;@display("t=13"); } <--> n1.g++;
        S.g++ <--> Link {  cost = 16;@display("t=16"); } <--> n2.g++;
        n1.g++ <--> Link {  cost = 1;@display("t=1"); } <--> n2.g++;
        n1.g++ <--> Link {  cost = 14;@display("t=14"); } <--> n3.g++;
        n1.g++ <--> Link {  cost = 9;@display("t=9"); } <--> n4.g++;
        n2.g++ <--> Link {  cost = 12;@display("t=12"); } <--> n4.g++;
        n4.g++ <--> Link {  cost = 20;@display("t=20"); } <--> T.g++;
        n3.g++ <--> Link {  cost = 4;@display("t=4"); } <--> T.g++;
        n3.g++ <--> Link {  cost = 7;@display("t=7"); } <--> n4.g++;
}
```

But I got this error when I try to run the simulator and it crash the exe file.

> Error in module (cModule) net.S (id=2) during network setup: Gate
>   `net.S.g$i[0]' is not connected to a submodule (or internally to
>   another gate of the same module).

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in `module Node`, which you declared as a compound module. OMNeT++ thus expects it to have submodules which connect to the declared gate `g`. However, your compound module has no submodules.

You most likely want to declare your module as `simple Node` (that is, a module without submodules).